# Как в VB добавить объект пользовательского типа в collection?

Tags: visual-basic

Объявляю пользовательский тип данных, создаю переменную этого типа и пытаюсь, методом .add, поместить в объект типа Collection, на что система выдает ошибку:

> Only user defined types, defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions

Вот, собственно код:

```
Type Task
    strDate As Date
    strName As String
    strStartTime As String
    strEndTime As String
End Type

Sub Test()

    Dim tskMyTask As Task
    Dim colMyCol As Collection

    colMyCol.Add tskMyTask

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно. Создайте модуль класса с теми же членами, работайте с ним.